# add a different ItemsSource for every row in a datagrid combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I need to declare a list of TextBox values and a ComboBox with some fields in it. Each ComboBox in every row might have 3 or 4 or 5 values,depending on what I pull from a database. But when I declare the fields, all the TextBoxes are binded properly, but the last ComboBox is always empty. I didnt add the TexBoxes and their code for clarity.
XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Finalize_routing}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="249" Width="582">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Stazione" ItemsSource="{Binding Station}" DisplayMemberPath="stazione_id" ></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
```

main class:

```
Finalize_routing = new ObservableCollection<Stazioni_operazioni>();                
Finalize_routing.Add(new Stazioni_operazioni
            {
                Station = new ObservableCollection<Stazioni> { new Stazioni { stazione_id="1"},new Stazioni { stazione_id="2"} }
            });
        }
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
```

stazioni_operazioni:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Stazioni> station;
    public ObservableCollection<Stazioni> Station
    {
        get { return station; }
        set
        {
            if (station != value)
            {
                station = value;

            }
        }
    }
```

stazioni:

```
public class Stazioni{
    public string stazione_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: solved by myself.i'll edit answer when i got some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was some problem with the class "stazioni", didnt figure out why.anyway i used a list of strings instead

```
final_route={"1","2","3"};
Finalize_routing.Add(new Stazioni_operazioni
    {
    Station = final_route
});
```

and xaml:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Stazione" Width="80">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Station,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```